# How to do INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE and update TIMESTAMP automatically?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table with PostgreSQL similar to this one:

mytable:

```
id
col2
col3
import_ts TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

So when I do an insert, I do not have to specify any value for this column and the current timestamp is automatically inserted.

However, when using a query like the following one:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, col2, col3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
                            ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
                            SET col2 = %s, col3 = %s;
```

the result is that in the case of `INSERT`, import_ts is automatically inserted, as expected; but in case of `UPDATE` the column `import_ts` will not be updated.

In order to have import_ts updated, as I am using `python` and `psycopg2`, I could add in `SET` `import_ts = %s` and pass the current time. However, it does not seem elegant and consistent that in one case the timestamp is added automatically and in the other one I have to add it. I would prefer that it is always done automatically by PostgreSQL. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use the [`now()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, col2, col3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
    SET col2 = %s, col3 = %s, import_ts = now();
```

Comment: I was thinking in telling somehow to SQL that I wanted the default to be used, but that is definitely simple enough. Thanks for opening my eyes ;)